# Initialize two struct members with a function that returns a tuple in Rust

Tags: struct, rust, initialization, tuples

So I have a function that returns a tuple of 2 values, and I want to assign these values to two different members of a struct. Is there a way to do this without having to call the function twice and extract each value individually?

I'm thinking something like:

```
let mut my_struct : MyStruct = MyStruct {
    (member1, member2): function_that_returns_tuple()
}
```

Currently I am calling the function on two temporary variables and then moving them to the struct members but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it directly in the initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your existing approach is the correct one. If you name the variables as the struct members, you can avoid the explicit `member: value` syntax:

```
let (member1, member2) = function_that_returns_tuple();
MyStruct { member1, member2, }
```